# C# : "Logon failure: unknown user name or bad password " error while using PROCESS.START() METHOD

Tags: .net, wpf, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I tried to login to gmail with the code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var user = new SecureString();
    foreach (char c in textBox3.Text)
    {
        user.AppendChar(c);
    }

    Process.Start("C:/Users/Indish/Desktop/chrome",
        "www.gmail.com", user, textBox4.Text);
}
```

The program says logon failure as mentioned in the question.So, if any one can help .........Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, you are using the wrong parameters for the overload of the method that you are using. The parameters are:

```
Process.Start(fileName, userName, password, domain)
```

So, you are sending `www.gmail.com` as user name, and the user name as password, that's why you get the error message that the login fails.

You need to use the overload that takes five parameters to send arguments and login to the method:

```
Process.Start(fileName, arguments, userName, password, domain)
```

However, that is used to provide a login for the user account that is used to run the program, not sending the login information to the program.

If the web page supports it, you can send login information in the URL:

```
Process.Start("C:/Users/Indish/Desktop/chrome", user + ":" + textBox4.Text + "@www.gmail.com");
```

Otherwise you would need to embed a browser control in your program to access the form after it has loaded.

Comment: No the error still exists after changing the code with five parameters.I USED: 
   Process.Start("C:/Users/Indish/Desktop/chrome","GMAIL",textBox3.Text, pass , "www.gmail.com");//The error comes with win32exception unhandled error.I used a try catch also to handle but it throws the exception every time I run the program

Comment: @IndishCholleti: Unless your computer is actually connected directly to the gmail network and you have a user account in the gmail network domain, you can't use a gmail account as login on your computer.

Comment: hey,I have those things ready.I am not so innocent to use this without having a gmail account.......

Comment: @IndishCholleti: A gmail account is not an account on the gmail network. If you are not physically connected to the gmail domain, i.e. it's part of your LAN, you can't use the gmail domain as a login on your computer.

Answer (score -1):

I can help you, however, where is the code you are using for the HTML interaction? Maybe I am misunderstanding. Are you posting these variables to the web server and checking the response, or are you using a no return method to just log in?

--EDIT--

I apologize, I am a little new to Stack Overflow's operations yet. What you will want to do for something like that is use a `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("IDNAME").SetAttribute("value", "data to put in");` on web browser inside of the application. In the case of FaceBook, the HTML of the website already has an  tag embedded on the box you are trying to set.

So, with this in mind, you can use the HTML ID of the tag by replacing "IDNAME" with "email" as is the ID for that box on FaceBook. You can do this for the entire login process (including using `webBrowser1.Document.GetElementByID("ID OF THE BUTTON HERE").InvokeMember("click");`

You can usually access the developer console as seen in my Chrome below via <kbd>F12</kbd>, or CTRL+SHIRT+C in Chrome, <kbd>F12</kbd> with FireBug in FireFox, and <kbd>F12</kbd> in IE. You are looking for a tool called "Inspect Element" to find the ID.

Comment: please move this answer to comment, its not an answer

Comment: I want the browser to insert the 3rd and 4th arguments directly into the username and password boxes of facebook.